# C Bitwise OR changing value unexpectedly

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-or

I'm currently writing a program that involves binary memory, and I need a certain bit sequence in a unsigned long long int.

Right now, I currently am looping through this block of code 4 times to attempt to create a 32 bit sequence.

```
unsigned long long int currentEntry = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j){
    currentEntry = (currentEntry << 8);
    currentEntry = (currentEntry | (unsigned long long int)entryBuffer[i][j]);
}
```

entrybuffer[i][j] is a char which contains a byte value which I cast into an unsigned long long int, and it seems to be working as far as I can tell, until I get a weird bug.
For example, here is the currentEntry variable in binary form:

```
//goal bit sequence: 00001000000001001010000011000000

currentEntry = (currentEntry << 8); 
//00000000
currentEntry = (currentEntry | (unsigned long long int)entryBuffer[i][j]); //entrybuffer[i][j] = 00001000
//00001000
currentEntry = (currentEntry << 8); 
//0000100000000000
currentEntry = (currentEntry | (unsigned long long int)entryBuffer[i][j]); //entrybuffer[i][j] = 00000100
//0000100000000100
currentEntry = (currentEntry << 8); 
//000010000000010000000000
currentEntry = (currentEntry | (unsigned long long int)entryBuffer[i][j]); //entrybuffer[i][j] = 10100000
//111111111111111110100000    (what?)*****
currentEntry = (currentEntry << 8);
//11111111111111111010000000000000
currentEntry = (currentEntry | (unsigned long long int)entryBuffer[i][j]); //entrybuffer[i][j] = 11000000
//11111111111111111111111111000000
```

I seem to be missing something obvious here, and I'm wondering if anybody can help me figure this out. I hope the code makes enough sense.

Clearly the bitwise OR is changing something, or something is overflowing somewhere, which is why I made currentEntry an unsigned long long int. I clearly only need 4 bytes of storage, and I understand this varies between machines, however I thought an unsigned long long int would be enough for my purposes.
If more information and context is needed, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: You are not compiling with warnings enabled are you (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`)? *strict-aliasing* rule?

Comment: What *is* `entryBuffer`? What is its *type*?

Comment: @Some programmer dude entryBuffer is a char. I'm also compiling with warnings, but not strict-aliasing rule I don't think.

Comment: the 2nd line of the for loop overwrites the value of `currentEntry` yet does not reference `currentEntry`.  What is `bitShifter`?

Comment: once you get this fixed - by masking the extended (i.e., casted) char with 0xFF as I suggest below - then have some additional fun learning about the assignment operators `<<=` and `|=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `char` can be either `unsigned` *or* `signed`, depending on compiler. In your case it seems to be `signed`.

That means when you cast it to a larger type you encounter something called *sign extension*. All the ones you see in the binary number is because of that and how [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) (the most common way to handle negative numbers) works.

If you want to store unsigned small 8-bit values use the explicit `uint8_t` type instead (note the `u` prefix, standing for `unsigned`). See e.g. [this fixed-width integer reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer#firstHeading) for more information.

Comment: actually it would work if the char, after extension to longlong, was masked against 0xFF.

Comment: @Some programmer dude Thank you! That works. Learned something new today. I knew it had to do with the two's complement of something, however I didn't know the char type could be signed or unsigned. I ended up just casting the entryBuffer as (unsigned long long int) (uint8_t) entryBuffer[i][j]) which is terribly ugly, but a quick fix.